# Unexpected exception occurs during producer/consumer code in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I was looking at a producer-consumer example with wait and notify, even though it works some times it gives exception. Not able to figure out where the problem is.

> Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(Unknown Source)  at com.bhatsac.workshop.producerconsumer.ProdNConsumer.consumer(ProdNConsumer.java:55)
>     at com.bhatsac.workshop.producerconsumer.ProdConsumerInvoker.lambda$5 (ProdConsumerInvoker.java:35)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ProdNConsumer {

LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
private int LIMIT = 1;
private volatile boolean shutdown = false;
private AtomicInteger counter=new AtomicInteger(0);
private Object lock=new Object();

public void produce() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized(lock){
            System.out.println("In producer :)"+ list.size());
            if(this.list.size()==this.LIMIT){
                try {
                    System.out.println("In waiting state producer");
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Produced by thread= "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
            list.add(counter.getAndIncrement());
            System.out.println("Going to sleep for a while");
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void consumer() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized(lock){
                System.out.println("In consumer :)");
                if(list.size()==0){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("In waiting state consumer");
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }   

                System.out.println("consumed by thread="+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                list.removeFirst();

                lock.notifyAll();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
 }



public class ProdConsumerInvoker {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ProdNConsumer pc= new ProdNConsumer();

    Thread tc1=new Thread(()->{pc.consumer();});
    new Thread(()->{pc.produce();}).start();
    new Thread(()->{pc.produce();}).start();

    Thread tp1=new Thread(()->{pc.produce();});
    new Thread(()->{pc.consumer();}).start();       
    new Thread(()->{pc.consumer();}).start();

    tp1.start();
    tc1.start();

}
 }
```

Comment: This exception is thrown during neither `wait()` nor `notify()`. Read the stack trace. Your `wait()`  calls should be inside a `while` loop, not an `if` block.

Comment: Yes, list.removeFirst() is throwing exception. But the list should not have reached to empty as the check is there on lists size. but still, it is throwing error.

Comment: For the reason I gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your producer and consumer threads are using the same lock. When a consumer wakes up and consumes an element, it calls `lock.notifyAll()`, which will wake up all consumers and producers waiting on it. Another consumer wakes up thinking there are items in the list, but it removes the first item from an empty list, causing the exception.

In the consumer, instead of `if(list.size()==0)`, use `while(list.size()==0)`. Similar reasoning applies to the producer as well. Just because the thread woke up doesn't mean that the condition it is waiting on is true. It only means that before the thread woke up the condition was true. It must check it again.

Comment: Yes that's exactly right, and it worked, instead of if we need to use while while(this.list.size()==this.LIMIT){
     try {
      System.out.println("In waiting state producer");
      lock.wait();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }